# What's the pythonic way of designing common class definitions in a package?

Tags: python-3.x, design-patterns

I'm coming from a C# background and have recently started to pick up Python 3. One thing that has lead to quite a bit of confusion so far has been how to structure modules in a package.

In C#, I would create a namespace `MyLibrary.Model`, in which all my different commonly used classes would reside, such as `User`, `Employee`, `Customer`, etc.. Each of these classes would be in their own file (e.g. `User.cs`, `Employee.cs`, etc.), since C# really doesn't care about files at all and only cares about which namespace a class belongs to. I would then import this in the various other bits of the library with `using MyLibrary.Model`, and all classes in that namespace would be available.

I have noticed that this is not how Python 3 likes to do things. Specifically, statements like "just import everything" seem to go against the design philosophy of Python, and instead, I am supposed to only `import` what I really need.

My question now is, how should I structure such common class definitions so it "makes sense" in a Python package?

### What I have tried so far

#### One class per file

This most closely mimics the "one class per file" convention in C#, leading to a directory tree as follows:

```
main.py
mylib/
    __init__.py
    common/
        User.py
        Employee.py
        Customer.py
    controller/
        ...
    ...
```

Back in the `main.py` file, I would write something like this:

```
from mylib.common.User import User;
from mylib.common.Employee import Employee;
from mylib.common.Customer import Customer;
```

This works, but it seems like it has a lot of verbosity that it really doesn't need.

#### All classes in one file

This seems to work better with the `import` system as I have understood it. Instead of putting every class into its own file, I would instead put every class into one file. The file structure would then look like this:

```
main.py
mylib/
    __init__.py
    common.py
    controller/
        ...
    ...
```

Back in the `main.py` file, I would write something like this:

```
from mylib.common import User, Employee, Customer;
```

This seems much more succinct, but I feel like with a bigger project, this could mean *a lot* of class definitions in one file, and possibly lead to `common.py` becoming a bloated mess, containing a lot of classes that don't really have anything to do with each other.

Comment: another option which I use sometimes is to put all classes in `common` and when using `import mylib.common as mdl`, then you can use `mdl.User`, `mdl.Employee`

Comment: @SamDaniel Is this commonly used? (No pun intended)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most larger projects I've seen split code into packages (directories) either by domain (`customer`) or function (`models`). These packages then had multiple modules with one or more classes in them (e.g. `customer/model.py`, `customer/view.py`... or `models/customer.py`, `models/employee.py`, etc.). Classes that were supposed to be exposed as package interface were then imported into package's `__init__.py` file which then allows user to write something like `from mylib.customer import CustomerModel, CustomerView` or `from mylib import customer` and then `m = customer.CustomerModel(...)`

[The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](https://docs.python-guide.org/) has a chapter covering general project layout from Python packaging perspective but also has bit on [Modules](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/#modules) and [Packages](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/#packages) - and basically gives similar set of recommendations there. That can be good starting point.

Good guidance in this can be also looking into existing popular projects that are larger and through some refactoring in past - like [Django](https://github.com/django/django), [Sphinx](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx) or [SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy).

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding your having accepted an answer quite early in the game, which might discourage further answers from being offered, I will offer my two cents:

Since I generally utilize the MVC design pattern, I therefore divide my packages into models, views (which usually utilize Jinja2 templates) and controllers. Then there are, of course, packages containing various utility classes etc.

I do not stick to a one-class-per-file rule. If classes are meant to work together cooperatively, they will be in the same file. Then again I might have a file containing multiple utility classes that have nothing in common other than their being utility classes or functions.

But what I really wanted to discuss is the great potential that lies is the use of the `__init__.py` file that often goes untapped when it is just an empty file. The answer by @blami made reference to this file but did not fully explain its usage. This file is meant to initialize the entire package. You can place in this file `import` statements to automatically load other modules and packages and/or any other initialization code. In your example (to which I added a missing `__init__.py` file -- there should be one in each directory that defines a *package*), we have

```
main.py
mylib/
    __init__.py
    common/
        __init__.py
        User.py
        Employee.py
        Customer.py
    controller/
        ...
    ...
```

**Possible Contents of mylib/**init**.py**

```
import requests # From the standard library, for example
from .common import * # This will use __all__ defined in the mylib.common package

VERSION = "1.1.1"
```

**Possible Contents of mylib/common/**init**.py**

```
__all__ = ["Employee", "Customer"] # from mylib.common import Employee, Customer
```

Note that in an `__init__.py` file for package `some_package` that the special variable `__all__` can be coded to specify a list of submodules to be imported from package `some_package` when the user writes `from some_package import *`. In the absence of variable `__all__` within the `__init__.py` file, the same import statement would just import the one package and whatever names are defined in that package and initialized by `__init__.py`.

Thus the next effect of the single statement `import mylib` is:

```
import requests, mylib.common.Employee, mylib.common.Customer, VERSION
```

So a judicious use of these `__init__.py` files can remove a lot of the bloat you were concerned about in using these classes.

Comment: It was a really difficult choice whom to give the bounty to, but this is a better self-contained answer and thus it gets my bounty.